# Multicolumn grouping and plotting

Tags: matlab

I have data that contain 55 columns and 24 rows. What I want to do is to plot every 5 columns in 1 figure. (to be more specific... columns 1-5 figure 1, columns 6-10 figure 2....and so on)

Every time I try a for loop I get lost. Can anyone help me?
It seems simple but I'm still learning how to use matlab.

Thank you for your hep

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over groups of 5:

```
my_array = zeros(24,55);
% fill my_array

for k = 1:11
    values_to_plot = my_array(:,5 * (k-1) + 1 : 5 * k);
    figure;
    plot(values_to_plot);
end
```

Comment: You appear to have your rows and columns reversed.

Answer (score 1):

To plot each column as a separate graph, in groups of 5 to a figure, you can use this:

```
A = rand(24,55); % the size of your array
for k=1:11
    firstCol = (k-1)*5+1;
    lastCol  = k*5;
    figure 
    plot(A(:,firstCol:lastCol));
end
```

Note that A(:,c) is the c-th column of A, and A(:,c1:c2) the columns from c1 to c2, inclusive.